# iPhone:app becomes "black" when msg "UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent is not available on this device." displayed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, video

In my application I record the video and play it. Most of the times video plays nice but sometimes in the middle of the playing video when I pressed "done" button in my log **"UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent is not available on this device."** msg displayed but how its generate that I don't know and when this msg generats my app becomes "black" and I have to delete it from background. Rest of the times my video works nicely and perfectly. 
In my info.plist file I changed necessary status bar settings but no effect in my result.

I want to mention that I am debugging my app from iPad.

and this msg does not generate every time.
I don't know why this msg displays.
Following code running on done button pressed.

```
- (void)moviePlaybackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [self stopMovie];
    NSLog(@"Start Timer Again");
   // [btnVideo setTitle:@"Start Recording" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnVideo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Record Button-iPad.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];

    NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                              nil];

    NSError *error;

    if (recorder) {
        recorder = nil;
        [recorder release];
    }
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];

    if (recorder) {
        [recorder prepareToRecord];
        recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
        [recorder record];
    }
    NSString *str = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"IMAGE_MOVEMENT"];
    NSLog(@"image movement %@",str);
    if(str == @"EASY")
    {
        NSLog(@"inside easy image");
        [self validateTimer];
        levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03 target:self selector:@selector(levelTimerCallbackEasy:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
    }
    else if(str == @"MEDIUM")
    {
        NSLog(@"inside medium image");
        [self validateTimer];
        levelTimerMedium = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03 target:self selector:@selector(levelTimerCallbackMedium:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
    else if(str == @"HARD")
    {
        NSLog(@"inside hard image");
        [self validateTimer];
        levelTimerHard = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03 target: self selector: @selector(levelTimerCallbackHard:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
    }
}

- (void)stopMovie
{
        NSLog(@"Stop Movie");


     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self 
     name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification 
     object:moviePlayer];

     // This trick is necessary, otherwise the screen remains black or will
     // flicker when you try to play the next video.
     [moviePlayer pause];
     [moviePlayer stop];
     moviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = -1.0;

     moviePlayer = nil;


    NSString *recorderFilePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    recorderFilePath = [recorderFilePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tempRecording.caf"];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:recorderFilePath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:recorderFilePath error:nil];
    }

    NSString *movieFilePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    movieFilePath = [movieFilePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"export.mov"];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:movieFilePath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:movieFilePath error:nil];
    }

    NSString *videoFilePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    videoFilePath = [videoFilePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.mp4"];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:videoFilePath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:videoFilePath error:nil];
    }

    NSURL *urls = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:recorderFilePath];
    NSError *err = nil;

    if (voiceRecorder) {
        voiceRecorder = nil;
        [voiceRecorder release];
    }

    voiceRecorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:urls settings:recordSetting error:&err];
    //[recorder setMeteringEnabled:YES];

    if(!voiceRecorder){
        NSLog(@"recorder: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        UIAlertView *alert =
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                                   message: [err localizedDescription]
                                  delegate: nil
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        return; 
    }

    //prepare to record
    [voiceRecorder setDelegate:self];
    [voiceRecorder prepareToRecord];
    //voiceRecorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
}
```

provide me any solution if you have.

thanx in advance.

Comment: till my knowledge UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent is being deprecated  by apple. so you need to find an alternative to this... Also... the code you have given is nothing to do with your question... problem is somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

iPad doesn't support UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent, change it to normal and you'll get rid of the error. Probably because they figured the big screen does not really need those extra 20 pixels anyway.

Comment: it is already in default stage I have not set it to "UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent" but why this msg generates that I don't know

Comment: @iPhone mmmm that is weird, something somewhere must be changing it, can you post the code that gets executed when the done button is pressed?

Comment: and when I run the same code in ipod  the msg "wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003" displayed and then the app becomes "black"